# Fetch API prints promise in incorrect order

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch the HTML script of two webpages using their URLs. This is my code:

```
const links = ["url1" : "https://.......", "url2" : "https://......"];
var responses = [];

for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(links)){ 
    let resp = fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest='+value)
    responses.push(resp);
}

Promise.all(responses)
    .then( htmlfiles =>{
        htmlfiles.forEach(file=>{
            file.text().then(function(data){
                gethtmldata(data);
            })
        })
     })
```

In my function `gethtmldata`, I am parsing this `data` in HTML format:

```
 function gethtmldata(html_data){ 
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var htmldoc = parser.parseFromString(html_data, "text/html");
    console.log(htmldoc); //shows data of url2, then url1
 }
```

---

To my utter surprise, the data of `url2` gets printed first, then `url1`. Why?

It should show the html data of `url1` then `url2`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably because `url1` finishes being fetched first. Why do you expect them to be in order? (They're _asynchronous_)

Comment: Is there a way to make it synchronous?

Comment: `fetch` is an async operation. You could try using a [synchronous http request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#synchronous_request), but that would block the page (not a good idea).

Comment: `[...: ..., ...]` isn't a thing…

Comment: You could fire each fetch one the other is complete? I still wonder why you need the files in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterations of your for loop aren't paused when you do `file.text().then(function(data){...}`. Instead, your loop fires off multiple `.text()` calls which will complete sometime in the future, with no guaranteed order on which ones will complete first.

You should `.push()` a Promise that resolves to your `.text()` data instead when you create `resp`:

```js
const links = {"url1" : "https://.......", "url2" : "https://......"};
const urls = Object.values(links);
const responses = [];

for(const value of urls){ 
    const txtPromise = fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest='+value).then(resp => resp.text());
    responses.push(txtPromise);
}

Promise.all(responses)
    .then(htmlData => {
        htmlData.forEach(data=>{
           gethtmldata(data);
        });
     });
```

You can refactor the above by using `.map()` and `async`/`await` like so:

```js
async function fetchHTMLData(urls) {
  const promises = urls.map(async url => {
    const resp = await fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest='+url);
    return resp.text(); 
  });

  return Primise.all(promises);
};

async function processHTMLData() {
  const links = {"url1" : "https://.......", "url2" : "https://......"};
  const urls = Object.values(links);
  const htmlArr = await fetchHTMLData(urls);
  htmlArr.forEach(htmlStr => {
    gethtmldata(htmlStr);
  });
}
```

Comment: it throws a error: `links is not iterable`

Comment: @Lubji What is links? Is it not an array?

Comment: No, it's an object

Comment: @Lubji I was actually assuming it was an array based on your original question before your edit. It still looks like an array though, but I guess it's an object? You can use `const urls = Object.values(links)` and then replace `links` with `urls` in the code above.

Comment: @Lubji I've updated the above code to deal with `links` as an object.